# Simulate Windows Media Player media sharing

Tags: arch-linux, media, streaming

My new TV can play media that's being shared by windows computers over the local network. Unfortunately, It only sees media that's being shared by Windows Media Player (not standard file sharing), and  I'm not really excited about having to reboot to windows whenever I want to stream something.

Is there software for Linux that sets up a media server similar to what WMP does (whatever the protocol is called)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard of the day is DLNA (Digital Living Network Alliance). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) has a partial list of software, but the easiest way is probably to try with something like [XBMC live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC_Live) (an Ubuntu-based live medium with XBMC on it) before you start installing things onto your work system.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your TV is expecting the same protocol my Xbox does. I stream to that with [ushare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/). It's easy to set up, but doesn't support transcoding, so the media needs to already be in a format the device can handle